Reduce Function - counting the number of months occurring in specified years
Hi I have the following table



Retro Start Date
Retro End Date
Total Invoiced Months
2009
2018
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024
2025




5/1/2020
3/31/2023
35
0
0
0
35
315
735
1155
0
0


7/1/2024
7/2/2024
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0


3/1/2024
6/30/2024
4
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
4
0


4/1/2024
6/30/2024
3
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
3
0



I want to calculate the number of months that each invoice occurs during the specific years. Rows 3,4,5; their invoices are occurring wholly within specific years (2024). Row 2 spans years, and the formula breaks.
The formula I have the works well if the invoice month range is only within a specific year is as follows:
=IFERROR(LET(a, $V$2#, b, YEAR(EDATE(Table2[@[Retro Start Date]], SEQUENCE(1,Table2[@[Invoice Months]],1,1)-1)), REDUCE(0, b, LAMBDA(x,y, x+IFERROR(XMATCH(a,b),0)))),)

Variables:

a - V2# is the header row - the headers of 2009, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025

b - YEAR(EDATE(Table2[@[Retro Start Date]], SEQUENCE(1,Table2[@[Invoice Months]],1,1)-1) -> here I make an array sequence of years that each month invoiced is in.


For the retro start date of 5/1, it should have 8 in 2020, 12 in 2021, 12 in 2022, and 3 in 2023.
If I wasn't trying to do this with array formulas I would use a countif function setting the headers (variable a) as the range and invoiced months (variable b) as the criteria.

So 7/1/24-7/2/24 should count as a month? i.e., any part of a month = 1 month?

Yes it should. Any part of one month shows one month.

Ok so I switched the variable b in the match function to y and it worked how I wanted it to. Folks - keep your variables in the proper scope!!
